# How to do slicing and use any() in python?

Tags: python, slice, any

I am trying to find the numbers smaller than the number(here i) towards the right of a list

If here 1,2,3,4 for any number there is no number towards its right which is smaller than that.I want to implement with any() and slicing.

But when I did that in python with the following code I am getting True but it should be False where am I missing the logic? and why is the output as True?

```
num=[1,2,3,4]

for i in range(1,len(num)-1):
    print (any(num[i+1:])<num[i])
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check what's actually happening here. You have:

```
any(num[i+1:]) < num[i]
```

`any` returns true if any of the elements of the list equivalent to true. Since all your numbers are non-zero, they are all equivalent to true. Then the right side compares to `True` to `num[i]`, so you have `True < 2` and `True < 3`. Since `True` is equivalent to `1` these both result in 1.

You probably want something like:

```
print( any(x < num[i] for x in num[i+1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `any` function should take a sequence of booleans, usually given by a generator expression. The reason your code outputs `True` is because `num[i+1:]` is a list of non-zero ints, which are considered "truthy", so the answer to "are any of them true?" is "yes".

You can write something like this:

```py
num = [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(1, len(num) - 1):
    print(any( x < num[i] for x in num[i+1:] ))
```

Output:

```
False
False
```